# Plot histogram of Sobel operator magnitude and angle in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I want to plot histogram in OpenCV C++. The task is that x-axis should be angle and y-axis should be magnitude of histogram. I calculate magnitude and angle by using Sobel operator. Now how can I plot histogram by using magnitude and angle?

Thanks in advance. The simple code of problem is

```
// Read image
        Mat img = imread("abs.jpg");
    img.convertTo(img, CV_32F, 1 / 255.0);
    /*GaussianBlur(img, img, Size(3, 3), 0, 0, BORDER_CONSTANT);*/
    // Calculate gradients gx, gy
    Mat gx, gy;
    Sobel(img, gx, CV_32F, 1, 0, 1);
    Sobel(img, gy, CV_32F, 0, 1, 1);

    // C++ Calculate gradient magnitude and direction (in degrees)
    Mat mag, angle;
cartToPolar(gx, gy, mag, angle, 1);
imshow("magnitude of image is", mag);
imshow("angle of image is", angle);
```

Comment: You may try the [OpenCV tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_calculation/histogram_calculation.html) which shows how to calculate and plot histograms you can skip the step of splitting the matrix since you have 1 channel in both cases

Comment: @api55 the issue is that I do not know how i can draw the Magnitude and Angle where i can put the these parameters in calHist function. Please can you give a little time to give code . I am just very beginner in opencv. Thanks.

Comment: Because I want angle on x-axis and magnitude on y-axis how can I draw it using Histogram. Please guide if possible using code .Thanks

Comment: Angles and magnitudes are just values, you have to know is the range, with angles you know it but with magnitude you may have to use minmaxloc find the maximum range. Then you use [calchist](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html). Then you will get the histogram, which you can plot them with any plotting library or in the link which i sent you before, they show how to do a super basic plot of the histogram.I will try to give you a complete answer later, if you still have problems

Comment: @api55 Thanks so much. me waiting your complete answer

Comment: probably you need [something like this](http://www.juergenwiki.de/old_wiki/doku.php?id=public:hog_descriptor_computation_and_visualization)

Comment: @sturkmen how can I apply on my code can you guide me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, So the first part of it is to calculate the histogram of each of them. Since both are separated already (in their own `Mat`) we do not have to split them or anything, and we can use them directly in the [calcHist](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html#calchist) function of OpenCV.

By the documentation we have:

```
void calcHist(const Mat* images, int nimages, const int* channels, InputArray mask, OutputArray hist, int dims, const int* histSize, const float** ranges, bool uniform=true, bool accumulate=false )
```

So you would have to do:

```
cv::Mat histMag, histAng;
// number of bins of the histogram, adjust to your liking
int histSize = 10;
// degrees goes from 0-360 if radians then change acordingly
float rangeAng[] = { 0, 360} ; 
const float* histRangeAng = { rangeAng };
double minval, maxval;
// get the range for the magnitude
cv::minMaxLoc(mag, &minval, &maxval);
float rangeMag[] = { static_cast<float>(minval), static_cast<float>(maxval)} ; 
const float* histRangeMag = { rangeMag };
cv::calcHist(&mag, 1, 0, cv::NoArray(), histMag, 1, &histSize, &histRangeMag, true, false);
cv::calcHist(&angle, 1, 0, cv::NoArray(), histAng, 1, &histSize, &histRangeAng, true, false);
```

Now you have to plot the two histograms found in `histMag` and `histAng`.

In the turtorial I posted in the comments you have lines in the plot, for the angle it would be something like this:

```
// Draw the histograms for B, G and R
  int hist_w = 512; int hist_h = 400;
  int bin_w = cvRound( (double) hist_w/histSize );

  cv::Mat histImage( hist_h, hist_w, CV_8UC3, Scalar( 0,0,0) );

  /// Normalize the result to [ 0, histImage.rows ]
  cv::normalize(histAng, histAng, 0, histImage.rows, cv::NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );

  // Draw the lines
  for( int i = 1; i < histSize; i++ )
  {
      cv::line( histImage, cv::Point( bin_w*(i-1), hist_h - cvRound(histAng.at<float>(i-1)) ) ,
                       cv::Point( bin_w*(i), hist_h - cvRound(histAng.at<float>(i)) ),
                       cv::Scalar( 255, 0, 0), 2, 8, 0  );
  }
```

With this you can do the same for the magnitude, or maybe turn it into a function which draws histograms if they are supplied.

In the documentation they have another option, to draw rectangles as the bins, adapting it to our case, we get something like:

```
// Draw the histograms for B, G and R
  int hist_w = 512; int hist_h = 400;
  int bin_w = std::round( static_cast<double>(hist_w)/static_cast<double>(histSize) );

  cv::Mat histImage( hist_h, hist_w, CV_8UC3, Scalar( 0,0,0) );

  /// Normalize the result to [ 0, histImage.rows ]
  cv::normalize(histAng, histAng, 0, histImage.rows, cv::NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );

  for( int i = 1; i < histSize; i++ )
  {
      cv::rectangle(histImage, cv::Point(bin_w*(i-1), hist_h - static_cast<int>(std::round(histAng.at<float>(i-1)))), cv::Point(bin_w*(i), hist_h),);
  }
```

Again, this can be done for the magnitude as well in the same way. This are super simple plots, if you need more complex or beautiful plots, you may need to call an external library and pass the data inside the calculated histograms. Also, this code has not been tested, so it may have a typo or error, but if something fails, just write a comment and we can find a solution.

I hope this helps you, and sorry for the late answer.

Comment: thanks so much @api55 for help me a lot. but the last section code of draw rectangle can not show any graph or points please can you check. they just show me rectangle not any points inside it.

Comment: my task is that x-axis should be angle and y-axis should be magnitude of histogram?. How can i get this?

Comment: @GujjarAd Yes, in a histogram you have bins, which have a bunch of point calculated. To plot Magnitude vs Histogram, it is easier, but I would recommend no to use OpenCV but a better library for that. Nevertheless is quite easy, just use the `circle` drawing function and draw it for each point

Comment: Please can little explain how circle draw using  plot Magnitude vs Histogram on it. I can not get your point. Thanks

Comment: @GujjarAd Wait a moment, I thought it was a plot of values of both of them separatedly. If both are together, then it can be calculated in opencv with the same calchist function, but the plot should be 3D (binx, biny, number of counts) .... so it cannot be done with opencv (maybe opencv viz3d) for that you will definetely need a plotting library.

Comment: so what Can I do now ?

Comment: @GujjarAd you can calculate the 2D histogram with OpenCV and then choose a library in c++ for plotting, I think Qt has something to help you, also there is a matplotlib wrapper too

Comment: how can i use  matplotlib wrapper? I am new tell me the easy way please

Comment: @GujjarAd You need to install python and matplotlib (easy thing to do) and then install the wrapper. [Here is the link](https://github.com/lava/matplotlib-cpp), and inside you have several examples and installing instructions